# How to present a Tabbar correctly? Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for tabbarcontroltest.ViewController:

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem showing a tabbarVC.

Here is the codes:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
    guard let vc1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "FirstController") as?  FirstController else {
        print("failed to get vc1 from Storyboard")
        return
    }
    guard let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondController") as? SecondController else {
        print("failed to get vc2 from Storyboard")
        return
    }
    guard let vc3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ThirdController") as? ThirdController else {
        print("failed to get vc3 from Storyboard")
        return
    }
    let vc4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
    let vc5 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
    let vc6 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3)
    
    vc4.title = "XXX"
    vc5.title = "YYY"
    vc6.title = "ZZZ"
    
    tabBarVC.setViewControllers([vc4,vc5,vc6], animated: false)
    tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(tabBarVC, animated: true)
}
```

}

The tabbar has shown correctly, but I got a warning of "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <tabbarcontroltest.ViewController:" which I don't understand.

Also I have tried to change

tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

to

tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

And, then I don't have this warning, but instead, when I try to close the app by home button,
I got another warning as

tabbarcontroltest[Presentation] Attempt to present  on <tabbarcontroltest.ViewController> (from <tabbarcontroltest.ViewController) which is already presenting .

I guess there is something wrong with the presentation style? Or is there something else wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found the solution by myself. the correct way is as follows:

```
    tabBarVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    tabBarVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    addChild(tabBarVC)
    view.addSubview(tabBarVC.view)
    tabBarVC.willMove(toParent: self)
```